# While executing NamedNativeQuery Join query after excluding the primary key using postgresql facing error

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I m not required id (primary key) in the resultant output but after excluding id in query and resultset getting error.org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id was not found in this ResultSet. jpa
SO need help in formatting this entity class.

**Note:** Assumption should be made like the below metthod call has been made entityManager.createNamedQuery("getPublisherInfoList",PublisherInfoResponseEntity.class).getResultList();

```
@NamedNativeQueries(value = {
@NamedNativeQuery(
name = "getPublisherInfoList",
query = "SELECT publisher.publisher_name,publisher.contact_name,publisher.contact_email,publisher.contact_phone,publisher.managed_services,\n" +
         "annual.customers,annual.employees,annual.revenue,"
     "FROM publisher_portal.publisher_informations publisher JOIN publisher_portal.publisher_annual annual\n" +
"ON publisher.publisher_name=annual.publisher_name",

resultSetMapping = "PublisherInfoResponseMappings"
),

@NamedNativeQuery(
name = "getPublisherByName",
query = "SELECT publisher.publisher_name,publisher.contact_name,publisher.contact_email,publisher.contact_phone,\n" +
"publisher.managed_services,annual.customers,annual.employees,annual.revenue,\n" +
"FROM publisher_portal.publisher_informations publisher JOIN publisher_portal.publisher_annual annual\n" +
"ON publisher.publisher_name=annual.publisher_name where publisher.publisher_name= :publisherName",
resultSetMapping = "PublisherInfoResponseMappings"
)

})

@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "PublisherInfoResponseMappings", entities = {
@EntityResult(entityClass = PublisherInfoResponseEntity.class, fields = {
@FieldResult(name = "publisher_name", column = "publisher_name"),
@FieldResult(name = "contact_name", column = "contact_name"),
@FieldResult(name = "contact_phone", column = "contact_phone"),
@FieldResult(name = "contact_email", column = "contact_email"),
@FieldResult(name = "managed_services", column = "managed_services"),
})
})


@Entity
@Table(name="publisher_informations",schema="publisher_portal")
public class PublisherInfoResponseEntity {


@Id
private Long id;

private String publisher_name;

private String contact_name;

private String contact_phone;

private String contact_email;

private String managed_services;

//setters and getters


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you want to exclude some column in resulset simply use **@Jsongnore** on that particular
column/field in your entity class.

**So the solution will be**

Include Primary key in query and result set but then use @Jsongnore on primary key so that the prepared resultset won’t have the field id.

**Note** you can apply @Jsongnore either at field or at getters method

**For Example**

```
@NamedNativeQueries(value = {
@NamedNativeQuery(
name = "getPublisherInfoList",
query = "SELECT publisher.id,publisher.publisher_name,publisher.contact_name,publisher.contact_email,publisher.contact_phone,publisher.managed_services,\n" +
         "annual.customers,annual.employees,annual.revenue,"
     "FROM publisher_portal.publisher_informations publisher JOIN publisher_portal.publisher_annual annual\n" +
"ON publisher.publisher_name=annual.publisher_name",

resultSetMapping = "PublisherInfoResponseMappings"
),

@NamedNativeQuery(
name = "getPublisherByName",
query = "SELECT publisher.id,publisher.publisher_name,publisher.contact_name,publisher.contact_email,publisher.contact_phone,\n" +
"publisher.managed_services,annual.customers,annual.employees,annual.revenue,\n" +
"FROM publisher_portal.publisher_informations publisher JOIN publisher_portal.publisher_annual annual\n" +
"ON publisher.publisher_name=annual.publisher_name where publisher.publisher_name= :publisherName",
resultSetMapping = "PublisherInfoResponseMappings"
)

})

@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "PublisherInfoResponseMappings", entities = {
@EntityResult(entityClass = PublisherInfoResponseEntity.class, fields = {
@FieldResult(name = "id", column = "id")
@FieldResult(name = "publisher_name", column = "publisher_name"),
@FieldResult(name = "contact_name", column = "contact_name"),
@FieldResult(name = "contact_phone", column = "contact_phone"),
@FieldResult(name = "contact_email", column = "contact_email"),
@FieldResult(name = "managed_services", column = "managed_services"),
})
})


@Entity
@Table(name="publisher_informations",schema="publisher_portal")
public class PublisherInfoResponseEntity {

@Id
@Jsongnore
private Long id;

private String publisher_name;

private String contact_name;

private String contact_phone;

private String contact_email;

private String managed_services;

//setters and getters


}
```

note:assume that entityManager.createNamedQuery(..) has been made